# Dequeue an element from a specific index

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue

Im trying to Dequeue a specific element from a LinkedNode queue. This is what i've got so far from another method that just removes and returns the first node in the queue(As it should in a queue). My question is How can I edit so that it will remove the element at index x? I included the javadoc psudocode to hopefully help.

```
 /**
 * Removes and returns the element that is at place x in the queue.
 * Precondition: x must be less than 5, x must be less than size
 * Note: indexing from 0: 0 == front element, 1 == second element, etc.
 * @param x the passed in index of the element to be removed
 * @return the element removed from the queue
 * @throws EmptyCollectionException if the queue is empty
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException if x > 4, or x > size of collection
 * 
 */

public T dequeue(int x) throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if (numNodes == 0) {
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("Work Ahead Queue");
    }
    T element = front.getElement();
    front = front.getNext();
    firstFive.remove(0);
    numNodes--;
    if (numNodes >= 5) {
        firstFive.add(firstFive.get(3).getNext());
    }
    return element;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A queue is a queue because it has an enqueue and a dequeue method, which add and remove from opposite ends of the queue respectively.  A queue is not guaranteed to provide other functionality.

If you wanted to remove a specific element in the middle, you could implement an algorithm that does this *on a queue* - for example, dequeue every element except the element-of-interest into another queue, and then enqueue them all again back into the original queue.

However, if you're going to be removing elements in the middle from your data structure, I doubt you really want to be using a queue at all.  There are far more efficient implementations for this operation on other data structures, such as (unconstrained) Linked Lists or indexed data structures.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. But basically i was simulating a restaurant. As the orders come in, typically they come out first come first serve, but sometimes the orders take a little bit longer so i wanted to ad a functionality
that could peek at the first 5 nodes in the queue to put in an arrayList, but also be able to Dequeue an element from somewhere in the firstFive nodes to simulate maybe is someone just ordered a salad and the other ordered a steak. the salad would obviously be ready first so i wanted to be able to take that out of the queue even though it wasn't the first in the queue.